# React Native Maps are grayed out on Android in my React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

I've looked at previous threads and followed this tutorial:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#deploying-google-maps-to-an-android-standalone

But still the map is gray on Android, just seeing the Google logo. It works fine on iOS (where I use the Apple-maps though..)

This is the relevant details:

The code in my expo app:

```
import MapView, { Marker, Callout, PROVIDER_GOOGLE, PROVIDER_DEFAULT } from "react-native-maps";

<MapView
        provider={Platform.OS === 'android' ? PROVIDER_GOOGLE : PROVIDER_DEFAULT}
...
</MapView>
```

The code in my app.json

```
"android": {
   "versionCode": 8,
   "config": {
     "googleMaps": {
       "apiKey": "xxxxxx"
     }
   },
```

I then create an APK development build, download it to my Android phone, start the server with expo start -c, open the app, and the map view is gray with the Google logo in the bottom.

I've tried:

- Creating a new API-key at Cloud Console
- Rebuilding the APK build with the new API key set in my app.json
- Setting the API-key in its Android restrictions with the bundle ID and the SHA-1 key as Fingerprint
- Making sure Maps SDK for Android under Enabled API's & Services in the cloud console.

But still having the same issues. What am I missing?

**React Native Maps Version**

1.7.1

**React Native Version**

0.71.8

**What version of Expo are you using?**

SDK 48

**Device(s)**

Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge

Comment: Does your device have google services?

Comment: Please note that it is considered best practice to use different API keys for different platform releases, and also different API keys between development and production builds. https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices